# Responsive Web Design - gap between elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive, semantics

I'm trying to create a responsive web by using `box-sizing: border-box;`
I am aware that most, if not all have their semantic tag aside on the left-hand side.
In my case, I have divided up two `sections` given 60% width each and `aside` with 40%
floating left side. The `aside` stay on the right side.

The issue I am having is the gap between `section.upper-sec` and `aside.right-col`
it would be logical if I arranged `aside` in-between of `section.upper-sec` and `section.lower-sec`

I have also tried with `aside.right-col` writing as first, then followed by sections.. however, I do not want the aside to be showing first at the breakpoint. Now I know that you can rearrange all elements with flexbox, but I am not confident enough with flexbox yet.

Second question is, is there any way to make `section.lower-sec` 100% height that leaves no gap between footer and vice versa for `aside.right-col` ?
[image: test]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Responsive Test</title>
    <style>
        *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        nav{
            background-color: #EEE;
            float: left;
            padding: 20px;
            width: 100%;
        }
            nav ul{
                list-style-type: none;
                text-align: center;
            }
                nav ul li{
                    display: inline;
                    text-transform: uppercase;
                }
        .left{
            background-color: #2196F3;
            padding: 20px;
            float: left;
            width: 13.5%;
        }
        .main{
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            padding: 20px;
            float: left;
            width: 55%;
        }
        .right{
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            padding: 20px;
            float: left;
            width: 31.5%;
        }
        section.upper-sec{
            background-color: grey;
            float: left;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 60%;
            text-align: center;
            height: 100%;
            outline: 1px solid red;
        }
        section.lower-sec{
            background-color: teal;
            float: left;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 60%;
            text-align: center;
            height: 100%;
            outline: 1px solid red;
        }
        aside.right-col {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column-reverse;
            background-color: green;
            float: right;
            text-align: center;
            outline: 1px solid red;
            width: 40%;
        }
        aside p{
            padding: 10px;
        }
            article{
                background-color: gold;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
            }
            #art1{
                margin: 10px;
                padding: 10px;
            }
            #art1 p{
                text-align: left;
            }
            #art1-W{
                text-transform: uppercase;
                font-size: 4em;
                font-weight: bold;
                float: left;
                margin-right: 5px;
                line-height: 0.8em;
            }
        footer{
            float: left;
            color: white;
            background-color: navy;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 800px){
            .left, .main, .right{
                width: 100%;
            }
            section.upper-sec{
                width: 100%;
            }
            section.lower-sec{
                width: 100%;
            }
            aside.right-col{
                width: 100%;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Test1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="left">
        <p>left</p>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <p>main</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <p>right</p>
    </div>
    <section class="upper-sec">
        <h1>Breaking News</h1>
        <h5>Headliner</h5>
        <p> News content </p>
        <p> News content </p>
        <p> News content </p>
        <p> News content </p>
        <p> News content </p>
    </section>

    <section class="lower-sec">
        <h1>Spotlight</h1>
        <h5>Opinion</h5>
        <p>News content</p>
        <p>News content</p>
        <p>News content</p>
        <p>News content</p>
        <p>News content</p>
        <p>News content</p>
        <p>News content</p>
        <p>News content</p>
        <p>News content</p>
        <p>News content</p>
        <p>News content</p>
        <p>News content</p>
        <p>News content</p>
        <p>News content</p>
        <p>News content</p>
        <p>News content</p>
        <p>News content</p>
        <p>News content</p>
        <p>News content</p>
        <p>News content</p>
        <p>News content</p>
        <p>News content</p>
        <p>News content</p>
    </section>

    <aside class="right-col">
        <p> Something on the right </p>
        <p> Something on the right </p>
        <p> Something on the right </p>
        <p> Something on the right </p>
        <article id="art1">
            <h1>‘The Godfather of trains’</h1>
            <h5>the Trans-Mongolian from Moscow to Beijing</h5>
            <p>For the author of Around the World in 80 
            Trains this was a standout journey, 
            full of captivating encounters that 
            could only happen on a train</p>
            <p><span id="art1-W">W</span> ith the air of melodrama unique to chic
            French women, the lady opposite me yanked open the overhead window then sat
            back down, grumbling to no one in particular and fanning herself with a
            copy of Paris Match. An aroma of pine filtered into the carriage and a
            breeze cooled my brow as the train clattered south to Béziers. Edging up to
            the window, I looked down to where a curl of sand and green water had
            appeared, an oasis where children bobbed about in dinghies and leapt off
            limestone rocks. This was the essence of why I love train travel: it allows
            me to see what’s behind the trees in the Massif Central; to smell the
            coconut being fried in huts in Kerala; and to spot rainbows hovering in the
            spray of Niagara Falls.</p>
        </article>
    </aside>
    <footer>
        <p>News & Media Limited or its affiliated companies. All rights reserved.</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Should the green box (.rightcol) be between upper-sec and lower-sec when the window is getting smaller in width? 

If so you can move the rightcol between upper-sec and lower-sec  and this will remove the upper right gap.

Comment: This will for sure remove the gap, but then again, this ruins my semantic flow structure

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into CSS grid for the main layout element positioning which is the current standard.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/
You can use it in combination with flexbox for the inner elements.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
It will also give you a better control over responsive design.